# Mutate set of columns conditional on set of columns with similar names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a number of columns (name starting with `var1`) each of which pairs up with another variable starting with `var2`. Like this:

```
df <- data.frame(var1_a_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var1_b_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var1_c_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var_something_else = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var2_a_num = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var2_b_num = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var2_c_num = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var_something_else2 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

For each of these pairs, I would like to create a new variable taking on a the value of `var1` conditional on the value of `var2`, or taking a `NA`. I can do this easily one by one:

```
df %>% mutate(var1_a_num_rec = ifelse(var2_a_num == 1, var1_a_num, NA))
df %>% mutate(var1_b_num_rec = ifelse(var2_b_num == 1, var1_b_num, NA))
df %>% mutate(var1_c_num_rec = ifelse(var2_c_num == 1, var1_c_num, NA))
```

But how to do this more efficiently, given I have lots of these pairs? NOTE: Want to avoid looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this.

It's not pretty and it's quite convoluted. 
If you execute each statement you can see how it works.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(union(starts_with('var1'), starts_with('var2')), 
               names_to = c('n', 'type'), 
               names_pattern = '(var\\d)_(.*)') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = n) %>% 
  mutate(rec = if_else(var2 == 1, var1, NA_integer_)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = c(var1, var2, rec)) %>% 
  select(-rowname) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(starts_with('rec')), ~str_c('var1', str_extract(.,'_.*'), '_rec'))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 11
#>    var_something_e… var_something_e… var1_a_num var1_b_num var1_c_num var2_a_num
#>               <int>            <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#>  1                9                9          9          5          9          0
#>  2                7                9          9          9         10          0
#>  3                6                3          1          4          3          0
#>  4                9                4          7          4          9          0
#>  5               10                6          1         10          9          1
#>  6                4                2          5         10          1          0
#>  7                4                2          1          3         10          0
#>  8               10               10          5         10          1          0
#>  9                4                4         10          4          7          1
#> 10                2                1          1          7          6          1
#> # … with 5 more variables: var2_b_num <int>, var2_c_num <int>,
#> #   var1__a_num_rec <int>, var1__b_num_rec <int>, var1__c_num_rec <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Data:

```r
df <- data.frame(var1_a_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var1_b_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var1_c_num = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var_something_else = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var2_a_num = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var2_b_num = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var2_c_num = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 var_something_else2 = sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks - however, two problems: (1) `starts_with('var1') | starts_with('var2')` does not work for me; but `union(starts_with('var1'), starts_with('var2'))` does. (2) In the last line, `~str_c('var1'...` instead of `~str_c('var1_'...` produces the correct naming

Comment: thanks for catching the typo in `~str_c('var1_',...)`. And good point on using `union`. Updated